# MIPS/MARS Runtime exception at 0x00400018: address out of range 0x00000000

Tags: runtime, mips, mars-simulator

Im trying to run some code in MARS, but i get a runtime error

the error happens at line 9

```
lb  $t1, ($t0)
```

my code is:

```
MAIN:   addi    $sp, $sp, -4  
sw  $ra, ($sp)  
add     $t6, $0, 0x30 # '0'
add     $t7, $0, 0x39 # '9'
add $s0, $0, $0
add $t0, $a0, $0
LOOP:
    lb  $t1, ($t0)
    slt $t2, $t1, $t6
    bne $t2, $0, DONE 
    slt     $t2, $t7, $t1 
    bne $t2, $0, DONE
    sub $t1, $t1, $t6
    beq     $s0, $0, FIRST
    mul $s0, $s0, 10

FIRST:
    add     $s0, $s0, $t1
    addi    $t0, $t0, 1
    j LOOP

DONE:
    add $v0, $s0, $0
    lw  $ra, ($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    jr  $ra
```

im fairly new to mips so i would love an explonation whats happening or is it just an syntax error ?

Comment: Not knowing anything at all about the mips/mars I can definitively say that this is **not** a syntax error as it is happening at runtime

Comment: @YePhIcK good point -

Comment: You are trying to read location 0 of memory which is not currently mapped. Usually this means that you have not loaded the register used to address memory. In this case `$t0` holds value 0, because `$a0` also holds that value. Also, were you trying to copy the contents of `$a0` into `$t0` when you issued `add $t0, $a0, $0` ? Instead of that use `move` instruction.

Comment: @gusbro - correct - will try with move instead